# Basic C++: convert from char to string

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm a little confused by the class code.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
//Program takes "string text" and compares it to "string remove".  Any letters in
//common between the two get deleted and the remaining string gets returned. 
#include <string>
#include "genlib.h"

string CensorString1(string text, string remove);

int main() {
    CensorString1("abcdef", "abc");
    return 0;
}

string CensorString1(string text, string remove) {
    for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++){
        for (int n = 0; remove[n]; n++){
            if (i != n){
                string outputString = ' '; //to store non repeated chars in,
                                           //forming my return string
                outputString += i;
                }
            }
        }
        return outputString;
}
```

1. I'm getting an error on the "outputString += 1" saying: "cannot convert from "char" to
   std::basic_string
2. I'm also getting an error on the "return outputString" saying: undeclared identifier
   ???????

I get that I'm putting a "char" on a "string" variable but what if shortly that "char" will soon be a string?  Is there a way to pass this?

I'm always forgetting libraries.  Can someone recommend a couple of standard/basic libraries I should always think about?  Right now I'm thinking , "genlib.h" (from class).

C++ is kicking my ass.  I can't get around constant little errors.  Tell me it's going to get better.

Comment: I hope you didn't really put `using namespace std;` in a header, did you? What are you trying to achieve by `outputString += i`?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag.

Comment: *C++ is kicking my ass. I can't get around constant little errors. Tell me it's going to get better.* It has, it's called Java or C#, with C++ you will forever be stuck with libraries that use different kind of character strings and unsafe conversions. Of course, having these libraries and access to OS functionality is a major reason to go with C++ in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in your code:

- Your `outputString` needs to be in the outer scope (syntax)
- You compare `i` to `n` instead of `text[i]` to `remove[n]` (semantic)
- You are adding `i` to the output instead of `text[i]` (semantic)
- You ignore the return of `CensorString1` (semantic)

Here is your modified code:

```
string CensorString1(string text, string remove) {
    string outputString;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] ; i++){
        for (int n = 0; remove[n] ; n++){
            if (text[i] != remove[n]){
                outputString += text[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return outputString;
}
```

This has some remaining issues. For example, using `text[i]` and `remove[n]` for termination conditions. It is also very inefficient, but it should be a decent start.

Answer (score 1):

At any rate, strings are *always* double-quoted in C and C++. Single-quoted constants are char constants. Fix that and you should probably be all right.

Also, look at this SO question: [How do you append an int to a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782/how-do-you-append-an-int-to-a-string-in-c)

Good luck at Stanford!

Comment: Thanks WN.  That was helpful.  The little things...  Now I just need to understand why I get the Error "undeclared identifier" for "return outputString".  didn't I identify it above?

Comment: @MCP because you're declaring 'outputString' in the scope of if statement. It gets destroyed when that scope ends. It needs to be at the function scope, so declare it at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems there:

`string outputString = ' ';` will try to construct a `string` from a `char`, which you can't do. You can *assign*  a `char` to a `string` though, so this should be valid:

```
string outputString;
outputString = ' ';
```

Then, `outputString` is only visible within your `if`, so it won't act as an accumulator but rather be created and destroyed.

You're also trying to add character indices to the string, instead of characters, which is not what I think you want to be doing. It seems like you're mixing up C and C++.

For example, if you want to print the characters of a string, you could do something like:

```
string s("Test");
for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    cout << s[i];
```

Finally, I'd say that if you want to remove characters in `text` that also appear in `remove`, you'd need to make sure that none of the characters in `remove` match your current character, before you add it to the output string.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of what I think you want, your code has multiple problems which just showed up described in multiple other answers.

```
std::string CensorString1(std::string text, std::string remove) {
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++) {
        const char ch = text[i];
        if(remove.find(ch) == -1)
                result.append(1,ch);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is actually pretty clean.  I'm assuing that implementation will be a lot less inefficient than my code?  I've got to get used to seeking member functions to complete a task...  Thanks JI.

Comment: When you're getting into it a bit more, you'll like iterators instead of the for loop above. Iterators are a bit harder to grasp, so I left them out of this simple implementation. When you feel more comfortable, look them up though :)