# C++ unknown errors

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, c++-cli

I have the following function in C++:

```
std::wstring decToDeg(double input)
{
    int deg, min;
    double sec, sec_all, min_all;
    std::wstring output;

    sec_all = input * 3600;
    sec = Math::Round(static_cast<int>(sec_all) % 60, 3); //code from @spin_eight answer
    min_all = (sec_all - sec) / 60;
    min = static_cast<int>(min_all) % 60;
    deg = static_cast<int>(min_all - min) / 60;
    output = deg + L"º " + min + L"' " + sec + L"\"";

    return output;
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What can I do to correct these two errors in my function?

**EDIT: solved**

```
std::wstring decToDeg(double input)
{
    int deg, min;
    double sec, sec_all, min_all;

    sec_all = input * 3600;
    sec = Math::Round(static_cast<int>(sec_all) % 60, 3);
    min_all = (sec_all - sec) / 60;
    min = static_cast<int>(min_all) % 60;
    deg = static_cast<int>(min_all - min) / 60;

    std::wostringstream output;
    output << deg << L"º " << min << L"' " << sec << L"\"";

    return output.str();
}
```

Comment: `sec_all` is `double`, the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Also, you're trying to sum numbers with strings, which can't be done like this in C++

Comment: Could you tell me what to do to solve these errors? I am totally new to C++...

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782/how-do-you-append-an-int-to-a-string-in-c for various ways to fix #2

Comment: Please don't write solutions in questions. Write solutions in _answers_.

Comment: This isn't C++. It's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a string stream to construct `output`, like this:

```
std::wostringstream output;
output << deg << L"º " << min << L"' " << sec << L"\"";

return output.str();
```

Comment: @Victor What error? BTW, of course you have to remove your original declaration of `output` as a `wstring`, and you have to `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sec = Math::Round(static_cast<int>(sec_all) % 60, 3);
```

Comment: output = std::to_string(deg) + L"º " +std::to_string(min) + L"' " + std::to_string(sec) + L"\"";

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use modulo on doubles.
Modulo on doubles:

```
 int result = static_cast<int>( a / b );
 return a - static_cast<double>( result ) * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first error try this:

```
 min = (static_cast<int>(min_all) ) % 60;
```

This should make sure the cast will be completed first, before trying to do any other calculating.

If your other error is not an error that was caused by the first error, you may want to try using [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/). It behaves like a normal I/O stream and is thus ideal for formatting strings.