# What is wrong with my 'Person' class?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person{
    public:
        Person(string n, int a, string g) {
            setName(n);
            setAge(a);
            setGender(g);
        }
        void setName(string x) {
            name = x;
        }
        void setAge(int x) {
            age = x;
        }
        void setGender(string x) {
            gender = x;
        }
        get() {
            return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + "\nGender: " + gender + "\n";
        }
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        string gender;
};


int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

That is my code, all I wanted to do was make a basic class with a constructer, with three parametres that defines the name, age and gender, for some reason, when I try and run this to check that everything is working fine, I get an error stating (line 23) : mismatched types 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator.

Can someone please help by fixing my code? I really don't understand what I've done wrong, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please point out which one is line 23 exactly? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
public:
    ...
    get() {
        return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + ... + gender + "\n";
    }
```

since the return value of this method is not defined and you are trying to append a value of `int` to `std::string` with `+`, which isnot possible. Since you need more complex output-formatting than just appending strings, you can use `std::ostringstream`:

```
public:
    ...
    std::string get() {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << "\nName: " << name << "\nAge: " << ... << gender << std::endl;
        return os.str();
    }
```

just don't forget `#include <sstream>`

---

Side note:

```
Person(string n, int a, string g) {
    setName(n);
    setAge(a);
    setGender(g);
}
```

is within the `Person` class, you can access `private` members directly:

```
Person(string n, int a, string g) : name(n), age(a), gender(g) { }
```

Comment: He said `using namespace std`, so `std::` is not required.

Comment: @Dgrin91: `using namespace std;` within global scope isn't a wise thing to do.

Comment: But never the less he did it. More importantly this is clearly homework code, and everyone does that in homework.

Comment: @Dgrin91: You should not do it, not even in homework. At least you'll get used to `std::` prefix.

Comment: This isn't homework code, I'm just having a bit of fun, I started learning javascript in march, got addicted, learnt python, loved programming, now i'm trying to learn C++, probably the most fun I've ever had, (fyi, this code helped a lot! thank you!) :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `get` function needs a return type. Furthermore, in C++ you can't just `+` strings and other objects together freely. Try using a `std::stringstream` instead, which will let you feed in strings, numbers, etc:

```
string get() {
    basic_stringstream ss;
    ss << endl
       << "Name: " << name << endl
       << "Age: " << age << endl
       << "Gender: " << gender << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

You'll need to add a `#include <sstream>` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add int type (age) to string type (name, gender). Convert age to string first.

Check [C++ concatenate string and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int)

Answer (score 2):

2 mistake in your code.

1.you are not using return value as string in your get method.
2.you cant add string and int directly.

Check how to add string and int [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782/how-do-you-append-an-int-to-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but I think its because your `get()` function does not declare a return type. It should be `string get()`. That being said, its a weird error message for such an error.