# How to add variable inside the cout?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I want to add float average variable inside the cout.
What's the perfect way for it?

```
int first , second , third;
cout<<"enter the first number: ";
cin>>first;
cout<<"enter the second number: ";
cin>>second;
cout<<"enter the third number: ";
cin>>third;

cout<<float average=(first+second+third)/3;
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64782/1025391 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/41364181/1025391

Comment: And because this might come up in the future too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/1025391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Just declare the variable before printing it.

```
float average = (first + second + third) / 3;
std::cout << average;
```

What you can do, however, is just not having the variable at all:

```
std::cout << (first + second + third)/3;
```

Also note that the result of `(first+second+third)/3` is an `int` and will be truncated. You might want to change `int first, second, third;` to `float first, second, third;` if that's not your intention.

Answer (score 1):

`float average=(first+second+third)/3;
cout<<average`

OR

`cout<<((first+second+third)/3)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable type first.

You can do something like this.

```
int first , second , third;
cout<<"enter the first number: ";
cin>>first;
cout<<"enter the second number: ";
cin>>second;
cout<<"enter the third number: ";
cin>>third;

float average;

cout<< (average=(first+second+third)/3);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ way would be:

```
float average = static_cast<float>(first + second + third) / 3.;
std::cout << average << std::endl;
```

Comment: The addition may overflow, might be better to divide before addition.