# How to add integer in a string?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, concatenation, operators

I want to append integer value with string value but not a variable.

I tried to put an integer value which is variable with a string called February. I tried it using += operator but it did not work.

```
string getMonth(day)
{
      if(day >=31 ){
          day -= 31;
          "February "+=day;
      }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append an int to a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782/how-do-you-append-an-int-to-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @NO_NAME it you see a dupe, just vote to close with respective reason (comment you have used will be auto added).

Comment: @MarekR I did just that? Well, I cannot vote to close because I don't have 3,000 reputation but I've clicked option `flag` and it auto-added the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like

```
#include <string>

// ...

std::string s( "February " );

s += std::to_string( day );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "February " );

    int day = 20;

    s += std::to_string( day );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
February 20
```

Another approach is to use a string stream.

Here is one more demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    int day = 20;

    oss << "February " << day;

    std::string s = oss.str();

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Its output is the same as shown above.

Comment: I included string still it shows : "to_string was not defined" error is shown."

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane If you copied the call exactly as it is written that is you used the qualified name std::to_string then maybe you need a more modern C++ compiler.

Comment: `std::to_string` is part of the standard since `c++11`. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @NO_NAME I am using dev c++ version 5.11

Comment: OK, Dev-C++ is an environment, not a compiler but close enough. Wiki says that it uses MinGW (basically GCC) in version that should support c++11. Maybe is is not default in this version? Try to manually add `-std=c++11` to compiler options.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am using "using namespace std" do i have to use std:: ?? I heard that using "using namespace std" is bad practic. Is it true?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane Yes in general it is a bad practice but for small programs there is nothing bad.

Comment: @NO_NAME how do I add std=c++11 in dev c++. Sorry if i am irritating you with these questions, but these are so new for me .

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane No idea. I've used Dev-C++ like 10 years ago but I've quickly stopped because this crashes was legendary (ah nostalgia). I remember nothing. Try to look in project setting for something names compiler arguments/options, though.

Comment: @NO_NAME thank u so much.. I appreciate your help..... I added that and it worked as well

Answer (score 0):

The answer above solved my problem.. If you are using dev c++ like me then you might be in the same problem, I would recommend you to add -std=c++11. For this you can got to this link [How to change mode from c++98 mode in Dev-C++ to a mode that supports C++0x (range based for)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran)  and go to second answer. Thank you